# Join two tables with multiple match with other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want join two tables as shown in image. The key value in seconded table occurs multiple times.
So, after join first tables entry must be repeated same times that matches all key and values in second table.

[image]

Comment: You 'forgot' to add column names to your tables...

Comment: "... as shown in image", please read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and ask yourself why you uploaded the image, because there is only some text in the picture.... (and even missing text )

Comment: Seems like a homework question. What have you tried already? What, if any, errors have you encountered?

Comment: You'll want to try a [left join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/left-join-right-join-operations-microsoft-access-sql), selecting Table A and left joining Table B. Also, see [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using a simple Left Join.

```
SELECT
    A.Column1,
    A.Column2,
    B.Column3
    FROM TableA A
        LEFT JOIN TableB B
            ON a.Column2 = B.Column4
```

Comment: The multiple match (see question) does not need a `LEFT JOIN`. The left join is only useful for getting the 'missing' match (TableA.Column1='y')